# Callback triggered by interactive radio button not working in Android/iOS App but does work on Desktop App

Tags: android, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

Hello dear slack community,

I was curious if someone also has noticed the following bug with the Slack Interactivity API.

Basically I created some radio buttons with the https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder, sent them via my PHP app and they successfully reach my slack client (both Android/iOS and desktop clients)

When I click on one of the radio buttons on the desktop client it successfully calls the URL defined in the Slack backends `Interactivity & Shortcuts` section but when I do the same on the Android/iOS App nothing happens (no request is being sent to the defined URL)

And yes, my receiving app behind the `Request URL` always returns a 200.

Any idea why it doesn't anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include `"dispatch_action": true` in your radio buttons block, as suggested in this answer https://github.com/slackapi/java-slack-sdk/issues/856

Comment: Indeed this is the solution. Slack Support answered me directly quite some time ago but I forgot to post the solution here.